# How to override Customer registration fields to custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, registration

I want to override Customer registration Fields to
my custom module

i copied the

```
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/ and Layout
```

to

```
app/design/vendor/child_theme/mymodule/layout and forms
```

in mymoduel/layout/index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="landingPagelayout3">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_layout3" template="Magento_Customer::/form/register.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info.layout3" as="form_additional_info"/>
            <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

in child theme  mymodule/form/register.phtml

```
  <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register $block */
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') ?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />

            <?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company') ?>
            <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone') ?>
            <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getFormData()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax') ?>
            <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getFormData()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('State/Province')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Country')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?= $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign-in Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required">
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create an Account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?= /* @noEscape */ $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-create-account"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**but only shows** 
1)First name 
2)Email
3)Password

**Not showing** 
1)City
2)Phone number
3)Address
4)Country

how to i do???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You tried the wrong way.

> app/design/vendor/child_theme/mymodule/layout

Should be

> app/design/vendor/child_theme/Magento_Customer/layout
>   app/design/vendor/child_theme/Magento_Customer/templates

Comment: is this procedure...

Comment: yes, this the way of overwrite in theme level

Comment: how it will takes that new page(can i change any thing)

Comment: Yes, you can modify theme level or use overwrite by the module. Don't modify core file

Comment: i tried not working ...

Comment: Your theme should activated, did you?

Comment: yes  vendor theme is always activated